# Nagios 3 and NSClient++

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I successfully installed nagios3 with nconf, everything works great, monitors linux machines with ease. Now the problem is I installed NSclient++ on my Windows Server R2, configured the IP to where my Nagios server is, but nagios 3 fails at getting all the needed info. Can anyone please help me regarding any configuration issues on NSClient or my server configuration for Nagios 3?

Comment: Can you get the info from the local cmd-prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually start the NSClient service? It is set to automatically start, but does not actually start automatically immediately following the installation.

Comment: Yes I did. When I start it, a command prompt comes on and off the screen. I've searched far and wide for answers and so far I found none.

Comment: Stop the service, then run NSClient++ in Test mode - it's one of the shortcuts you've got there. That will show you what's going on - it'll output what it's doing each time a command comes in.